# HTTPResponse.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'content_type'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Error -

TypeError at /api/
HTTPResponse.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'content_type'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/
Django Version: 4.0.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
HTTPResponse.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'content_type'
Exception Location: D:\Python_Tutorials\DJango\PracticeDjango\Rest_Practice\withoutrest\testapp\views.py, line 17, in emp_data_json_view
Python Executable:  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.5
Python Path:
['D:\Python_Tutorials\DJango\PracticeDjango\Rest_Practice\withoutrest',
'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python310.zip',
'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs',
'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib',
'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310',
'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages',
'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32',
'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Sat, 20 Aug 2022 17:29:03 +0000

```
from http.client import HTTPResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
import json
# Create your views here.
def emp_data_json_view(request):
    emp_data = {'eno': 100,
                'ename':'sunny',
                'esal' : 1000,
                'address' : 'Pune'
                }

    # dumps() -> coonvert python dict to json
    # loads() -> convert json to python dict
    #converting pytohn dictionary to json data

    json_data = json.dumps(emp_data)
    # if we did not mention content type - it will be consider as HTTP response only
    return HTTPResponse(json_data, content_type = 'application/json')
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made changes to code and used JsonResponse directly than HTTPRespons
And that worked for me.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def emp_data_json_view(request):
    emp_data = {'eno': 100,
                'ename':'sunny',
                'esal' : 1000,
                'address' : 'Pune'
                }
    return JsonResponse(emp_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I had a wrong import error in my code.

I have replaced this

```
from http.client import HTTPResponse
```

with this

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

Then, I have used JsonResponse rather than HTTPResponse.

so my code now is

```
#from http.client import HTTPResponse
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
import json

# Create your views here.

def emp_data_json_view(request):

    emp_data = {'eno': 100,
                'ename':'sunny',
                'esal' : 1000,
                'address' : 'Pune'
                }

    return JsonResponse(emp_data)
```